# Can't initialize class caused by udf in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I tried to use a udf in my function and call this function in my main function. I get no error in compile. But when I tried to run this application, it gave out error: Can't initialize class with main class name with line number of udf was given. Below is code structure：

```
object shuffle {
create logger, conf, sparksession...
def main(): Unit = {
    get configuration from file
    val df = read in data
    try {
       val finaldf = my_function(df)
       finaldf.write_back_as_parquet
    } catch {
       deal with exception
    }
    end
 }
def my_function(arg : DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val dateConverter = udf((ts : String) => DateFormat.format(new Date(ts.toLong * 1000))) <----------error message point at this line
    arg.withColumn("ts", dateConverter($"value"))
        .withColumn("hh", lit(23)).withColumn("mm", lit(59))
 }

}
```

I get confused. Why I get this error? Is there any rule of where I shall put my udf?

Comment: udf should be defined before being called. It would be helpful if you update your post with the code you are using to call the udf function

Comment: you still haven't updated how you are calling the dateconverter udf function code. And please update with the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

`withColumn` api should be used to call the `udf` function. I guess you missed that part. So here's what you can do

```
def my_function(arg : DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val dateConverter = udf((ts : String) => DateFormat.format(new Date(ts.toLong * 1000))) 
     arg.withColumn("dateConvertedColumn", dateConverter(col("ts")))  //<---- ts is the column name of the string date you want to convert. 
    ...
 }
```

Comment: actually, I use the udf with `withColumn`.  And I am trying to reproduce the error with my laptop after that I will update the error message.

Comment: currently no. I try to achieve same environment like server side. I can't reproduce this in total local environment.

Comment: @G_cy didn't the answer helped you ? if it did please consider accepting it and upvoting it